# How to remove first three harmonics from a daily data time series?

Tags: time-series, fft

I have the time series of a meteorological variable - Daily data for 10 years.

Time series

[image: 1]

I would like to remove the first 3 harmonics from the time series.

I don't come from EE background, and finding it tough to understand Fast Fourier Transform.

How can I proceed with this? A python or R example would be great.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to filter the data. When you say first 3 harmonics, I assume you mean low frequencies. So you're probably looking for some kind of high pass filter.

Answer (score 2):

As @simple_code mentioned, if you **don’t** care about the signal components *prior to* and *in-between* the harmonics, you can just apply a high pass filter with a cut-off frequency above the 3rd harmonic.

If you **do** care about signal components *prior to* and *in-between* the 3 harmonics, then you’d want to go for 3 **notch filters**.   Scipy has what you need if working in Python.

Let me know if you need more help